# Efficient way to get rows immediately outside of a time window

Tags: clickhouse

We have time series data stored in a clickhouse table, similar to:

```sh
timestamp             value
2020-03-05 11:03:00    2
2020-03-05 11:12:00    3
2020-03-05 11:13:00    4
2020-03-05 11:27:00    5
2020-03-05 11:31:00    6
2020-03-05 11:39:00    7
```

When visualising this data, we request a time range, like `2020-03-05 11:15:00` - `2020-03-05 11:30:00`.

It is easy to select data within this range, but what is more useful for visualisation is to also get the points either side, i.e.:

```sh
2020-03-05 11:12:00    3
2020-03-05 11:13:00    4
2020-03-05 11:27:00    5
2020-03-05 11:31:00    6
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in clickhouse? At the moment I am doing (potentially) 3 separate queries:

1. Select data within range:

```sql
select * from data where timestamp >= "from" and timestamp <= "to" order by timestamp
```

2. If timestamp of first point != "from" timestamp:

```sql
select * from data where timestamp < "from" order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

3. If timestamp of last point != "to" timestamp:

```sql
select * from data where timestamp > "to" order by timestamp limit 1
```

It would be great if it were possible to get this in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like need just combine all three queries to one and a little change the comparison operators:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
      /* test data */
      SELECT data.1 AS timestamp, data.2 AS value
      FROM (SELECT arrayJoin([(toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:03:00'), 2), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:12:00'), 3), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:13:00'), 4), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:27:00'), 5), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:31:00'), 6), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:39:00'), 7)]) AS data)
  )
  WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:15:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:30:00'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        /* test data */
        SELECT data.1 AS timestamp, data.2 AS value
        FROM (SELECT arrayJoin([(toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:03:00'), 2), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:12:00'), 3), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:13:00'), 4), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:27:00'), 5), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:31:00'), 6), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:39:00'), 7)]) AS data)
    )
    WHERE timestamp <= '2020-03-05 11:15:00'
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        /* test data */
        SELECT data.1 AS timestamp, data.2 AS value
        FROM (SELECT arrayJoin([(toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:03:00'), 2), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:12:00'), 3), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:13:00'), 4), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:27:00'), 5), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:31:00'), 6), (toDateTime('2020-03-05 11:39:00'), 7)]) AS data)
    )
    WHERE timestamp >= '2020-03-05 11:30:00'
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC
    LIMIT 1))
ORDER BY timestamp;
/* result
┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┐
│ 2020-03-05 11:13:00 │     4 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:27:00 │     5 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:31:00 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
*/
```

```sql
..
WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:13:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:30:00'
..
/* result
┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┐
│ 2020-03-05 11:13:00 │     4 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:27:00 │     5 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:31:00 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
*/
```

```sql
..
WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:15:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:31:00'
..
/* result
┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┐
│ 2020-03-05 11:13:00 │     4 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:27:00 │     5 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:31:00 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
*/
```

```sql
..
WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:27:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:31:00'
..
/* result
┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┐
│ 2020-03-05 11:27:00 │     5 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:31:00 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
*/
```

```sql
..
WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:28:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:28:00'
..
/* result
┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┐
│ 2020-03-05 11:27:00 │     5 │
│ 2020-03-05 11:31:00 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
*/
```

```sql
..
WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:31:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:31:00'
..
/*
result
┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┐
│ 2020-03-05 11:31:00 │     6 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks reasonable. I'll test it with some real data. But why the `SELECT DISTINCT`  on the 2 outside points?

Comment: *SELECT DISTINCT* is required to case when *"from" == "to"* (like this, *WHERE timestamp > '2020-03-05 11:31:00' AND timestamp < '2020-03-05 11:31:00'*).

Comment: This worked well. No faster than the individual queries of course, but saved network trips.

Answer (score 0):

I would expand range by some function toStartOfTenMinutes('2020-03-05 11:15:00)
toStartOfTenMinutes('2020-03-05 11:30:00')+600 , or -600 +600

And filter excessive rows at the client side. 
Because 3 queries are slower than 1.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but the problem is that we only get rows when there is a change in value. This means that some data can have hours or even days between points while some change every second. Having a set expand range will miss points for some series and get way too many extra for others.

Comment: @JeffWilliams you can use toStartOfInterval() and specify a custom interval (days, hours, seconds, etc)